# Timed procedures tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is [date-and-time](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date-and-time) tag appropriate for this question and similar ones:

[ScheduledTask with scoped variables. Working with timed evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38291/5478)

[TagWiki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date-and-time) is no so precise but one can say it includes `ScheduledTasks` related questions.

On the other hand timed evaluation is something important, not so obvious and ususally not well documented in terms of *possible issues* and **I think there should be a sperate tag** for questions about `ScheduledTasks`, `Pause` and evaluation order, e.g:

[queued evaluation from a Dynamic GUI without using a Button](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19174/5478)

[Evaluation order of Button[]'s action](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19556/5478)

---

Please upvote only the answer (one for each tag) that you prefer!

Comment: Perhaps [tag:real-time]?

Comment: @OleksandrR. Oh thanks, I don't know how I've missed that tag. But imo the name is not accurate enough, especially if it goes about questions like that two from links at the end. But I'm not an IT specialist so maybe it is the proper name.

Comment: Kuba, you didn't miss anything with the tag Oleksandr suggested, as it only has 8 questions and not even a short description. I say it is not a good candidate, as it is not well defined and it could be used in practically any question, as most calculation is done in real time. Will think of a better tag...

Comment: @IstvánZachar I disagree. "Real time" has a very precisely defined meaning, which is that the correctness of the result depends not only on its value but also its timeliness. For example, calculating yesterday's weather forecast, or a stock ticker for an hour ago, is not a useful result. These are real-time calculations. Most calculations are absolutely not of this type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a tag that applies to cases where a combination of the followings apply:

- **timing and/or temporal order is important during evaluation/runtime;** [timing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timing) [evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evaluation)
- computation results in a dynamically maintained object rather than a static one; [dynamic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic)
- producing/manipulating real-time continuous data/streams; [streams](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/streams) [real-time](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-time)
- synchronized parallel computation is to be used; [parallel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallel)
- scheduled tasks are possibly involved.

Though for each subdomain, there are appropriate tags, I do agree that it would be useful to have a tag that covers all. Furthermore, there is no tag for scheduled task, which is a pity, concerning that it gains more and more momentum being useful in many situations.

**My candidate tag is: [scheduling](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scheduling)**, with an appropriate specifier from the above list depending on the question asked.

Comment: This description is perfect! I think [tag:scheduling] covers this well. On the other side I'm not sure if the name is "common" enough. What I mean is, as non-native english speaker, after reading a description what comes to my mind is something like [tag:evaluation-order]. But maybe I didn't get used to english enough :) but this may be important when someone new is going to search for something.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, I thought of [tag:evaluation-order] myself, as it links really tightly to the concept of sequence-of-evaluation. The only thing against it is that while `order` specifies chronological order it does not refer to temporal intervals of events. That might be unnecessarily abstract for the discussion, but for me it is like talking only about the list of stops of a bus line without actually specifying the route the vehicle takes with all its details, obstacles and delays. I have to admit, `sheduling` is similarly missing (directly) the concept of order.

Comment: Agree, but imo tag should be intuitive/handy/simple and details can be included in tagWiki. So better that one will find less accurate tag, and then it's good description, than will not find at all. scheduling would be easy to find only for people asking/looking for question directly related with `ScheduledTask`.

Comment: I see your point @Kuba, and I find [tag:evaluation-order] equally fitting. Perhaps let the community decide which one they prefer, by posting a second answer! You should do it so that I can cast my vote :)

Comment: Scheduling is also a discipline in [computer science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)). It also deals with timing and with order of evaluation. But I would see this as downside to this name, as I feel that classifying something in a class that it almost belongs to makes terminology fuzzy.

Comment: Please @Kuba go ahead with the wiki. Unfortunately I have very limited time due to grant applications, so I am really thankful if you could do it!

Comment: Ok, done, waiting for review. I mostly used your description. Not sure if acknowledging you by name is appriopriate there I've left link to the meta discussion. Good luck with the applications.

Answer (score 2):

**My proposition is: [evaluation-order](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evaluation-order).**

tagWiki would be the same as proposed by [István Zachar](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/89/istvan-zachar) with addition names it is related to: `ScheduledTasks`, `Pause`, `PreemptProtect`, `Method->"Queued"/"Preemptive"` etc.

For cons and pros of both tags I'm referring to comments below István' answer.